# In an ng-repeat, how can I send objects with a falsey value to the bottom of the div?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```html
  <div class="well" ng-repeat = "artist in artists" align="center" ng-model="artist">
   <img src={{artist.pic}} alt=""> <br/>
    {{artist.title}}
    {{artist.year}}
    {{artist.genre}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="favorite(artist)" ng-show={{artist.favorite}}>Unfavorite</button>
     <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="favorite(artist)" ng-hide={{artist.favorite}}>Favorite</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(artist)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

I want to order the artists depending on if the `artists.favorite` is true or false, currently, they are just being listed as they are in the array. Would I need to create a custom directive? Thank you!!!

Comment: Sounds like you want to be sorting the artists array. You could do this in a Controller, or you could use a filter - check out the orderBy filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: Perfect, thats just what I needed, i just added `| orderBy:'-favorite'` after artist in artists and it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: You can create a custom filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `| orderBy: '-favorite'` after `artist in artists` and that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter with the ng-repeat.

```
ng-repeat = "artist in artists | orderBy:'-favorite
```

More on orderBy [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).